# Can not remove gray line between table head and body

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am generating a table in MVC view. The code is vary simple.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Company Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Contact Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Contact Title
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
            <th>
                City
            </th>
            <th>
                Region
            </th>
            <th>
                Country
            </th>
            @*<th></th>*@
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactTitle)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Region)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap and in view I have written following style code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    thead {
        background-color: #337aff;
        color: white;
        border-bottom-width: 0px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}

    table {
        border: 2px solid #337aff;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0cm 0cm;
        font-family: verdana;
        border-bottom-width: 5px;
    }
    tbody {
        border-top-width: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

The problem is that there is a very tiny gray line between **thead** and **tbody** and also between two **tr**, although I make **border-collapse**: *collapse* and **border-spacing**: *0cm 0cm*;

I have no idea why this is happening, perhaps for bootstrap.css file.

Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Thanks
Partha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"**border-top**" is set to thead, tbody, tr and td in "tables.less" file which is in "Bootstrap" itself, so you can remove the tiny gray line by using "**border: 0;**" in your CSS, something like this:

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th,
.table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th,
.table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th
{
  border: 0
}
```

Complete code: [Remove tiny gray lines](https://codepen.io/Adeel91/pen/jmxgwX)

Comment: you can also use `border-top: 0;` instead of `border: 0;` and if you just want to remove the gray lines between two "tr" then just `.table > tbody > tr > td` would work and remove others from your CSS file

Comment: Working! Thanks.